# Laravel new threads to appear before bumped threads

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a forum thread table, that are linked to a comments table

I would like to order my query by their latest comment, and a new thread to appear before that

At the moment, new threads are appearing last

Ideally I need new threads with no comments to appear above them ones and not order after ones with comments? If that makes sense

This picture should explain

[image]

The order should be:

- Fifth Thread (because created last)
- Third Thread (should be 2nd because it has a comment before fifth thread was made)
- FourthThread
- Second Thread
- First Thread

Here is my Query

```
public function getThreads($limit = 30)
{
    return ForumThread::select(DB::raw('forum_threads.*, count(*) as count'))
        ->where('cat_id', $this->id)
        ->where('published', 1)
        ->join('comments', 'comments.thread_id', '=', 'forum_threads.id', 'left outer')
        ->orderBy('pinned', '1')
        ->orderBy('count', 'desc')
        ->orderBy('comments.created_at', 'desc')
        ->groupBy('forum_threads.id')
        ->paginate($limit);
}
```

have tried to explain the best I can

Comment: Shouldn't your query contain `->orderBy('forum_threads.created_at', 'desc')` if you want the newest threads to appear first?

Comment: Are you sure you really want that? As this means a thread without comment will always appear above thread without comments – you will be required to have at least one comment in each to make it go away.

Comment: @Matey: that would not make the threads with a recent comment show in their place.

Comment: @tanerkuc I thought the thread creation time had priority over comment creation, based on "I need new threads with no comments to appear above"

Answer (score 0):

You would have to make a conditional column that has the value of what is newer, the thread creation date, or the latest comment creation date.

Something like this:

```
IF(forum_threads.created_at > comments.created_at, forum_threads.created_at, comments.created_at) as last_activity_at
```

Better would be to make the first post of a thread its own `Comment` that is attached to the `Thread`. So every thread would have at least 1 comment. Just subtract one from the comment count to count the number of "replies". This will make your database structure cleaner and won't be replicating columns in both the thread and the comment tables.